# What is the right syntax for ng-show with scope variable

Tags: angularjs, uiview

I am setting a ng-show for when I have certain state so my delete button should be shown.

But it's not working. I checked in the console and my method is passing true to the scope variable. Still not sure what is wrong.

application.html

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-show="notesState" ><a  ng-really-message="Are you sure you want to delete this note?" ng-really-click="deleteNote(note)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "  style="float:left;" >Delete note</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/home" >+ New Note</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="signedIn"><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="signedIn"><a href="#/home">{{user.email}}</a></li>
        <li class="pointer" ng-show="signedIn"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
```

in notesCtrl.js

```
$scope.notesState = $state.is('notes')
```

Comment: is the `signedIn` variable working?

Comment: Yes. They work just fine

Comment: I realizes I was having $scope defined in the wrong controller. But then changed to the proper one and the prob remains. 
If I set it with ng-hide it weirdly shows, but in all states. not only in notes as supposed

Comment: if it shows with ng-hide then it must have a falsy value (it could be undefined, and empty string, etc)

Comment: I thought of that. But I placed a console.log in the controller and $state.is('notes') is returning true. I can't manage to debug the value that is in ng-show="notesState" though

Comment: you could add {{noteState}} on top of the <ul> element to test the value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is notesState true when the controller is loading?  you might need to $scope.$apply() if it something that is false when the controller loads but becomes true later.

sometimes returning a function works but i really do not know why you would need to do this.

$scope.notesState = function(){ return $state.is('notes') }

ng-show="notesState()"

here is $state.is and the function it sometimes returns

```
$state.is = function is(stateOrName, params, options) {
  options = extend({ relative: $state.$current }, options || {});
  var state = findState(stateOrName, options.relative);

  if (!isDefined(state)) { return undefined; }
  if ($state.$current !== state) { return false; }
  return params ? equalForKeys(state.params.$$values(params), $stateParams) : true;
};
```

and

```
function equalForKeys(a, b, keys) {


 if (!keys) {
    keys = [];
    for (var n in a) keys.push(n); // Used instead of Object.keys() for IE8 compatibility
  }
  for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    if (a[k] != b[k]) return false; // Not '===', values aren't necessarily normalized
  }
  return true;
}
```

if that helps anyone looking into this.

Comment: returning it as a function worked. I just wonder why it didn't the other way. since $state.is('notes') returns true shouldn't that be assigned to notesState?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way.May be it works.

```
<li ng-show="notesState=='true'" >
```